# Material Select menu with checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I'm looking for create a select menu with integrated checkbox.
I have 3 menus, first select role user and the 2 second, user access.
If I select admin user on the first menu , I want to have 2 next menu all checked.
But i can't select 2 role user at the same time.

so this is my code

Ts file (not all the code, just the part who I need )

```
    fixture_access_list = [];
    group_access_list = [];
    role_list = [];

    form: FormGroup;
    formSubmitAttempt: boolean;
    isPasswordVisible = false;


    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService, public dialog: MatDialog, public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CreateUserDialogComponent>) {

      this.role_list = [
        {id: 1, viewValue: "Admin" },
        {id: 2, viewValue: "Client"}
      ];

      this.fixture_access_list = [
        {id: 1, viewValue: "Reading"},
        {id: 2, viewValue: "Editing"},
        {id: 3, viewValue: "Flipping"},
        {id: 4, viewValue: "Locating"}
      ];

      this.group_access_list = [
        {id: 1, viewValue: "Reading"},
        {id: 2, viewValue: "Creating"},
        {id: 3, viewValue: "Editing"},
        {id: 4, viewValue: "deleting"},
        {id: 5, viewValue: "Flipping"},
        {id: 6, viewValue: "Locating"}
      ];
    }
```

HTML

```
 <mat-list-item class="primary-menu-item" role="listitem">
            <mat-form-field class="select-form">
              <mat-select
                placeholder="Role User"
                name="RoleUser"
                class="filter-select"
                multiple>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let role of role_list" [value]="role">
                  {{role.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </mat-list-item>


          <mat-list-item class="primary-menu-item" role="listitem">
            <mat-form-field class="select-form">
              <mat-select
                placeholder="Fixture Access"
                name="FixtureAccess"
                class="filter-select"
                multiple>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let fixture of fixture_access_list" [value]="fixture">
                  {{fixture.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </mat-list-item>


          <mat-list-item class="primary-menu-item" role="listitem">
            <mat-form-field class="select-form">
              <mat-select
                placeholder="Group Access"
                name="GroupAccess"
                class="filter-select"
                multiple>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let group of group_access_list" [value]="group">
                  {{group.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </mat-list-item>
```

Comment: I think you may need to use checkboxes for some of these fields instead of radio buttons. https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview

Comment: Hi, can you try to add a trackBy function? (e.g. `*ngFor="let item of collection;trackBy: trackByFn"` in HTML; and in TS `trackByFn = (item)=> item.id`)

Comment: No I have no try this, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow only one option to be selected from a `mat-select`, don't use the `multiple` option:

```
<mat-select
  placeholder="Role User"
  name="RoleUser"
  class="filter-select">
```

To select items in one list based on the selected option in another list, use the `selectionChange` event on the 'control' list to set the value of the selections in the 'target' list:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Role User" name="RoleUser" class="filter-select" 
    (selectionChange)="roleChanged($event.value)">
  ...
</mat-select>

<mat-select placeholder="Fixture Access" name="FixtureAccess" class="filter-select" multiple 
    [value]="selected_fixture">
  ...
</mat-select>
```

TS:

```
selected_fixture = [];

roleChanged(role) {
  if (role.id === 1) {
    this.selected_fixture = [...this.fixture_access_list];
  } else {
    this.selected_fixture = [];
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y8zv2o?file=app/list-overview-example.ts